# c++ operator overloading in template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, template-classes

I´ve developed an template class.
Now I want to overload the lower than operator.
I tried it normally, like with a normal class, but it doesn´t work.

Event.h

```
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H

#include<string>
#include <functional>

template<class T>
class Event
{
public:
    Event(std::string Name, std::function<T ()> fnktptr, int time, Event*resultingEvent);
    virtual ~Event();
    bool operator < (const Event &e) const;
    std::string Name;
    Event *resultingEvent;
    int time;
    std::function<T ()> fnktptr;
};

#endif // EVENT_H
```

Event.cpp

```
#include "Event.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
Event<T>::Event(std::string Name,std::function<T ()> fnktptr, int time, Event*resultingEvent) : Name(Name), fnktptr(fnktptr), time(time), resultingEvent(resultingEvent)
{
    //ctor
}
template<class T>
Event<T>::~Event()
{
    //dtor
}
template<class T>
bool Event<T>::operator < (const Event& e) const
{
  if(this->time < e.time) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

// No need to call this TemporaryFunction() function,
// it's just to avoid link error.
void TemporaryFunction ()
{
    Event<int> TempObj("",nullptr,0,nullptr);
}
```

main.cpp

```
Event<int> *event1 = new Event<int>("sadfsf", nullptr, 5, nullptr);
Event<int> *event2 = new Event<int>("sadfsf", nullptr, 4, nullptr);
if(event1 < event2) {
    cout << "event1 is lower" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "event1 is greater" << endl;
}
```

The program prints "event1 is lowert".
But if my overloading function would work, "event2 would be greater"
(I compare the time 5 in event1 with the time 4 in event 2)

Comment: Template class functions as well as operators overloaded for them must be defined in the .h file.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @SergeyA, I defined it in the header `bool operator < (const Event &e) const;``and implement it in the *.cpp.

Comment: @NathanOliver, It compile with the linker workaround `TemporaryFunction`

Comment: @alexander-fire How did you actually manage to [provide the template implementation in a translation unit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)?

Comment: @alexander-fire, and this is exactly what I mean. You do not define it, you declare it in a header.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ By never actually calling it, so that function is never instantiated, so it never has to link.

Comment: @Barry Sure, that's why I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not comparing what you think you're comparing:

```
if(event1 < event2) {
```

`event1` and `event2` both have type `Event<int>*`. Pointers have a builtin `operator<`, which does something that is entirely unrelated to what it is you want to do. If you want to compare the actual `Event<int>`s that are pointed to, you'll have to dereference them:

```
if (*event1 < *event2) {
```

at which point you'll run into the issue that [templates can only be implemented in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/2069064).

Comment: oh. Thank you.

I made the comparing overloading for my priority_queue. What should I do for that?

`std::priority_queue<Event<T>*, std::vector<Event<T>*>> q;`

Comment: @alexander-fire Hint: `priority_queue` takes three template parameters.

Comment: I know, but there I have another problem. (See edited question.)

Comment: @alexander-fire Please don't update questions to new questions - it invalidates existing answers. I rolled back your edits.